# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value In mongoose with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The error:

```
**CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 60b881468beb8518ace49e81" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Blog"**
    at model.Query.exec (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4473:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4567:15)
    at D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\app.js:84:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at logger (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\morgan\index.js:144:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7 {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '" 60b881468beb8518ace49e81"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: ' 60b881468beb8518ace49e81',
  path: '_id',


  **reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters**
      at new ObjectID (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
      at castObjectId (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:245:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1105:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1583:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1573:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1550:20)
      at cast (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:331:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4912:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1954:10)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2211:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
      at D:\Git\Node\node-crash-course\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11),
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

**My app.js code**

```
app.get('/blogs/:id',(req,res) =>{
    // console.log(req.params.id);

    const id = req.params.id;

    Blog.findById(id)
    .then((result) =>{
        res.render('details',{blog:result,title:'Blog Details'})
        // console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    })
})


**And details.ejs code** 

    <title>Document | <%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>

   <%- include('../partials/nav.ejs') %>

     <div>
         <h2>Hellow World</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="blogs">
         <h1>Blogs</h1>
 

                <h3 class="title"> <%= blog.title %> </h3>
                <p class="snippet"> <%= blog.snippet %></p>

                 </a>
     </div>
```

How can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can understand what is happening by reading the log

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 60b881468beb8518ace49e81" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Blog"**
```

The code related:

```
const id = req.params.id;
Blog.findById(id)
```

In your code above, you get the id from request parameters and use it to search for the blog. From the error, I think the value of `id` is `" 60b881468beb8518ace49e81"`. It has an extra space at the beginning. Mongoose cannot "convert" it to a valid ObjectId, which is expected by `findById` method. Hence the error.

I think we need to remove all unnecessaries spaces from the string, try this

```
const id = req.params.id.trim(); // call trim method to remove extra space at the beginning/end of the string
Blog.findById(id)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I try many ways to fix this I didn't see the extra space at the beginning. now I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: `You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle`